# Once universal regex for tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I've these strings:

```
"#ab#ab #ab # ab #  a  #a   "
```

**and**

```
"ab ab ab  ab   a  a   "
```

so I want get this from the strings:

```
"ab ab ab ab a a"
```

(without leading and last space)

**But**

now I use two regexes:

`replace(/#/gi, ' ')` **and** `replace(/ (?!\w)/gi, '')`

and my regexes are not perfect. I want use one nice regex.

Can you help me?

Comment: I remember this question (or a similar one) being posted a few hours ago.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337362/universal-regex-for-tags

Comment: You have to be more specific. Are the hashes (`#`) and spaces significant? If so, how are they significant? Should any whitespace character be considered, in addition to just spaces? Regular expressions are powerful, but if you don't define them very carefully you will end up with the wrong result. If you just want the alpha characters matching something like `/[a-z]+/` should do just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following regex(Thanks to [@Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj))

```
[\s#]+
```

Also use `trim` on the replaced string to remove leading and trailing spaces if any.

Demo:

```js
var str = '#ab#ab #ab # ab #  a  #a';
str = str.replace(/[\s#]+/g, ' ').trim();

console.log(str);
document.write(str);
```

[**Regex Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/vX8yH9/2)

```
/\s*(?:#|\s)\s*/g
```

1. `\s*`: Matches any number of spaces
2. `(?:...)`: Non-capturing group
3. `#|\s`: Matches `#` literal **or** a space character

```js
var str = '#ab#ab #ab # ab #  a  #a';
str = str.replace(/\s*(?:#|\s)\s*/g, ' ').trim();

console.log(str);
document.write(str);
```

Comment: Thank you! But your regex is not universal so it cant parse "ab ab ab  ab   a  a   "

Comment: @StanKnock The second option `var str = '#ab#ab #ab # ab #  a  #a';
str = str.match(/\w+/g).join(' ');` does

Comment: try `str.replace(/\s*(?:#|\s)\s*/g, ' ').trim();`

Comment: @AvinashRaj you should post that as answer

Comment: Avinash, can you post ur comment as answer?

Comment: @AvinashRaj post ur comment as answer, please. You solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: or `str.replace(/[\s#]+/g, ' ').trim();`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thank you!

Comment: @StanKnock it's ok. I derived the solution from Tushar's answer. Credit must go to him only..